# external IP access to subsite gives me no webparts

Tags: 2013

I'm creating subsites in a Sharepoint 2013 site, if I access the subsites via an internal IP it goes well but if I access the same site from an external IP with the same user no webparts appears in the subsites.

update:

I have found that someone changed the name of the server after Sharepoint installation so it seems that sometimes there are redirections to the old name, so can I change something or I will need a new installation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure all addresses you use to connect your SP site in the Alternate Access Mappings in CA? This includes IP addresses if you use them to access your sites (i.e. wihtout a domain name).

Comment: Hi Evariste, I have found that someone changed the name of the server after Sharepoint installation so it seems that sometimes there are redirections to the old name, so can I change something or I will need a new installation?